# Print option for rotate 180° even pages only on Mac

Tags: printing, network-printer, hp-laserjet

I'm trying to print an horizontal Pages document (double-sided) or a PDF, but the even pages are always upside down. How can I set my HP LaserJet 2600n printer to print horizontal documents correctly?

Currently to do this correctly, I have to export the document to a PDF, rotate the pages with Pdfsam, save it and then print. This too much work for simply printing a document!

Does anyone know a faster way to print horizontal documents?

Answer (score 1):

As you mention "even pages", I assume you are printing double-sided.

When selecting duplexing, you can select either "flip on long edge" (the default) or "flip on short edge". The exact wording may be different on your printer, but the options will be there.

With portrait documents you would normally use the default, unless you want to print the pages in "notebook" format. However, with landscape you need to think about how the document will be used and select the appropriate option. In your case that would be "flip on short edge".

Comment: For some reason, the option Duplex is overlined, if I click on it I read this in an unsupported option for this architecture... sobb!